# .Net - Add existing element to powerpoint presentation slide

Tags: c#, .net, copy, powerpoint

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint to edit slides in Presentation.
I need to get some element from one slide and insert it in some other slide.
Since this is a web project, I am trying to avoid using the clipboard.
Does anyone have some experience in this, is it possible with using Interop only?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this being a web project and why that would be a consideration?  My take on this is that if you're automating PowerPoint, you're automating it on the PC where it resides; it's that PC's clipboard that's involved, not some other box's clipboard.  I'm probably missing something here, though.

Comment: I have web app that allows user to create, edit and download presentations.

Comment: Without more detailed information, I doubt whether anyone can help you with this.